# Will defining functions within the constructor consume more memory than attaching it to prototype?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, prototype

This would presumably be the safest way (*Case A*):

```
var myClass = function() { };
myClass.prototype = {
    doSomething : function() { alert('Something'); }
};
```

This is the alternative (*Case B*):

```
var myClass = function() {
    this.doSomething = function() { alert('Something'); };
};
```

I'm under the impression that by doing this as shown in Case B, doSomething would be a member, and the function would be defined once for each myClass object I instantiate so that it will exist 100 times in memory for 100 instances, whereas in Case A the function will only exist in one place in memory and different instances will merely reference the prototype.

**Am I understanding this correctly?**

**As a bonus question**: When doing it as in Case B, chrome developer gives me intellisense for doSomething, but I must expand __proto__ for an instance to see it. How come it doesn't show up on the object itself? That is, why doesn't prototype members show on the object, but get stuck back down on __proto__? I would have preferred if the __proto__ stack would get flattened and show up on the object directly. Is there another Case that will allow this to happen?

Comment: Case B should be `this.doSomething = ...`, but yes, it will create a separate function for each instance.

Comment: Anyone for answering the bonus question? :)

Comment: @Mithon: Apparently the decision of the Chrome developers was to reflect the prototype chain correctly instead of flattening it. The property don't show in the object because the object really does not have that property (try `obj.hasOwnProperty('doSomething')`). Seeing the actual chain is much better for debugging, since you can see which property might shadow an other one. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, in case B, you are merely creating a global function, not attaching it to the instance. You meant:

```
this.doSomething = function() { }
```

Secondly, the first will be faster. Though I can't find the link now, jQuery honcho John Resig did a detailed blog post on this showing speed tests on prototypal inheritance of methods vs. methods declared on the instance. Inheritance was notably faster.

In terms of ethos, I've always much favoured inheritance. This is the place for reusable, cross-instance functionality. Adding it to each instance has the sole benefit of allowing you to declare methods inside a single, convenient closure, in your constructor, but that's it.

If this is your reason for liking pattern B, it's possible to do this whilst still a) having the methods inherited; b) not redeclaring them at every instantiation.

```
function SomeClass() {
    if (!SomeClass.prototype.someMethod) {
        SomeClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {}
    }
}
```

This will slightly slow down the initial instantiation, though, as it is responsible for setting up the prototype - not really the job of an instantiation process.

There is also a programmatical difference to be aware of between your two cases:

```
 function SomeClass(name) {}
 SomeClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {};
 var instance = new SomeClass();
 console.log(!!instance.someMethod); //true
 console.log(instance.hasOwnProperty('someMethod')); //false
```

The last line is false because the method is inherited, not owned by the instance. With your pattern B, this will resolve to true.

Comment: Actually I preferred Case B, since I felt pretty sure that it would work as I described and as has been confirmed. However a coworker didn't think I was right, hence this question. =) Your added pattern C is a nice variation, but I don't like to add extra unneeded conditionals, even if the slowdown will be negligible in almost all cases. The hasOwnProperty was nice extra information for me. Tyvm.

Comment: Class B is fine but it will be slower and it's against the principle of prototypal inheritance - the prototype is the place for reusable functionality, not the instance itself. Good luck either way.

Comment: Ohh.. sorry.. I mixed up which case was which. What I said did not make sense just now. I meant Case A, since it's the one with the inheritance working. Anyhow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Correct: defining methods in the prototype will create 1 function object, and every instance will reference that 1 function. Defining it in the constructor creates a new function for each instance
2. Your code needs some work. The way you're defining the constructor, the `doSomething` function is defined **as a global** add `var` to counter that. This still doesn't set `doSomething` as a property though, it's just a function declared within the scope of the constructor (closure). This is why it doesn't show up in your instance as a method: the function is not attached to `this`, but even when fix this issue like so, you're still creating new function objects for each instance:

---

```
 function MyConstructor()//capitalize constructors - conventions are important
 {
     var someMethod = function(){/*..*/};
     this.someMethod = someMethod;
 }
```

Utkanos pointed out what the implications of inheritance and prototype methods are (`.hasOwnProperty`), and he's absolutely right in that respect (+1). I'd just like to add that the `hasOwnProperty` method returning false is a trivial matter. Generally speaking, when iterating over an object, and checking which properties and methods are set, and which are not. What you want in most cases are properties, not the methods. So it's in fact better to set them at the prototype level:

```
for(var name in obj)
{
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name))
    {
        //do stuff, here the methods are set @ prototype level
    }
    if (obj.hasOwnPrototype(name) && typeof obj[name] !== 'function')
    {
        //same stuff, but requires extra check when methods are assigned by constructor
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you favour function MyConstructor() {} over var MyConstructor = function() {} ?

Comment: Actually, yes: I use `var someF = function(){}` to distinguish constructors from regular functions. To be honest, I use `var someF =` almost exclusively for closures, I know I should use `var myFunc(){}` more often but old habits die hard, I guess... good question though, didn't really give it much thought while typing my answer

Comment: Hmm.. I think I'll adopt that as a policy. :)

Comment: Or maybe not. Seems I can't do that when I have a namespaced class.

Comment: @Mithon: I wouldn't go as far as to say that my habits should be regarded as `good practice`, well at least not _by definition_ ;-P, but this style makes the distinction clear to me, when I use constructors (I don't use them very often any more. I had a youtube-Crockford OD, every time I type `new` I see his beard and hear a reminder that `new` can be avoided in 90% of cases)

Comment: @Mithon: nitpicking: JS doesn't have classes :)

Comment: Sure.. no classes.. but while it sometimes makes communication hard if you're not strict, sometimes it's the opposite. In this case I think the meaning was clear. Anyhow.. Your habit seemed good for a coding standard. But again it doesn't work with my requirement to use namespaces, (from what I can tell anyhow,) so scratching it

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph of the answer, it is kind of implying that iterating over an object's properties and using `hasOwnProperty()` won't give you methods, but that's not right: methods are just properties that happen to reference functions. (Probably you didn't mean to imply that methods are different, but that's how it read to me.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: you're right, it was ambiguous. I've edited my answer to clarify what I meant. thanks for the heads up. Mithon: yes, it was clear from the context what you meant, that's why I said I was nitpicking. You're right to say my approach doesn't work with namespaces as such, but you could wrap the namespaces in a self-invoking function and use that function's scope, sadly that will make the code messier rather then cleaner, so yes, I suppose you're better of leaving it at that. Happy coding